# when trying to set crossorigin attribute on video tag video playback is damaged

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, video, cors

The issue occur on chrome browser desktop.
I'm getting the following error when trying to add track element to the video:

```
  <video ...>
       <track..>
    </video>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/itayKinnrot/6Up5t/1/

when i'm adding the **crossorigin** attribute to the video (as the error suggest) the video playback is damaged (when trying to resume the video after pause - no playback + error from the video element)
http://jsfiddle.net/itayKinnrot/PrCZ5/1/

what am i'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that in your second fiddle, the resource request (of the video) is being 302-redirected.
It seems that Chrome does not properly handle CORS-enabled videos after a redirect (possibly due to a bug in the implementation that handles buffering/caching).

This is how it looks like in the network tab of the developer tools:

[image]

After replacing the `src` attribute of the video tag with the target of the redirection, I can properly seek through the video and pause/resume the playback. The network log shows successful byte range requests. Note that the developer tools did not show chunked responses for the first request, but only one continuous request.

[image]

This behavior screams "bug", so opening a new issue at http://crbug.com/new seems to be the best course of action. Try to create a small test case (preferably self-contained) to make it easier to pin-point the bug. Please add a comment with a link to the bug report when you've created the issue.